# How to trigger tab load in jquery tabs component

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

How to perform below load tab with jQuery UI 1.10?

```
$(".selector").tabs("load",tab_index);
```

Above one is not working with new version. If anybody has idea about to use tabs with jQuery UI ver 1.10.

Comment: maybe you should trigger it upon `click()` since tabs are made up of `<a> anchors` ?

Comment: No when i am doing click trigger. it is going to the tab. not reloading the content.